# Why is lazy evaluation in Haskell "not being lazy"?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

When I tried the following code in cghi:

```
take 1 $ take 1 $ repeat [1..]
```

I was expecting the result of `1` instead of `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...` printing on my terminal.

Why is lazy evaluation not functioning as I'm hoping under such situation?

Comment: If it weren't being lazy, it would loop forever *without anything being printed* (because it would have to calculate the full result before printing any of it and since that'd take forever, nothing could ever be printed).

Comment: What were you hoping would happen instead?

Comment: You probably meant `take 1 $ take 1 $ repeat 1` (bdonlan's answer explains why). It really is lazy.

Comment: The result of `take 1 $ take 1 $ repeat [1..]` *is* `[[1..]]`, so ghci is giving you the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`take` is of type `Int -> [a] -> [a]`, i.e. it returns a list. It seems you’re looking for `head`, which returns one element.

```
head $ head $ repeat [1..]
```

Answer (score 6):

`take 1 $ repeat [1..]` returns `[[1..]]`. And then `take 1 [[1..]]` returns `[[1..]]`, a no-op.